# Additional dynamic feature to javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

I am working for an additional feature to a dynamic javascript form. On top is the form and underneath a table that gathers all the information from the form. The form has an additional feature possibility but I struggle adding that information to the table. If I succeed in adding it to the table console gives me an error when user doesn't want to add an additional feature. This is the current code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
$('form#search-form').bind('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tbody = $('#product-list > tbody');
    tbody.append('<tr><th scope="row" style="background-color:' + this['new-product-color'].value +
        '"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></th><td>' + this['product-name'].value +
        '</td><td>' + this['product-price'].value + '</td><td>' + this['product-link'].value +
        '</td><td>' + this['product-currency'].value + '</td><td>');
        // + this['additional-info'].value
    return false;
});
```

});

The one that is commented out is my code that adds the additional feature to the table if I include that to tbody.append-part. How can I make this work?

Code for the additional feature:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add-new").click(function() {

      var newInput = $("<div class='newfeature'><p>Additional info <button id='remove'>Remove feature</button> </p> <input name='additional-info' value='' id='additional-info' type='text' class='searchbox' placeholder='Additional info'></div>");
      $('input#product-currency').after(newInput);
      $("#remove").click(function() {
        $(newInput).remove();
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: `If I succeed in adding it to the table console gives me an error when user doesn't want to add an additional feature`, what error?

Comment: Use Obj.hasOwnProperty("<property name>") to check if the 'additional-info' property exists before accessing it

Comment: app.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined